pyTelegramBotAPI: StateMemoryStorage not working correctly
I'm writting a task-tracker bot using telebot. In message_handler for a new task by using callback_data I check which button was pressed. I need a way to get message.text after the button was pressed and save it.
import telebot
from configobj import ConfigObj
from telebot import types
from telebot import custom_filters
from telebot.handler_backends import State, StatesGroup
from telebot.storage import StateMemoryStorage

# Чтение конфигурационного файла
config = ConfigObj('config.ini')

# Получение токена из конфигурационного файла
TOKEN = config['telegram']['token']

state_storage = StateMemoryStorage()

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN, state_storage=state_storage)


# Определение состояний
class TaskStates(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    description = State()
    deadline = State()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    start_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    new_button = types.KeyboardButton('Новая задача')
    exists_button = types.KeyboardButton('Существующая задача')
    report_button = types.KeyboardButton('Отчеты')
    start_markup.add(new_button, exists_button, report_button)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери команду', reply_markup=start_markup)


# Обработчик кнопки 'Новая задача'
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Новая задача')
def handle_new_task(message):
    new_task_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

    name_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Название', callback_data='name')
    description_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Описание', callback_data='description')
    deadline_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сроки', callback_data='deadline')
    save_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сохранить задачу', callback_data='save')
    back_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Назад', callback_data='back')

    new_task_markup.add(name_button, description_button, deadline_button, save_button, back_button)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите данные:', reply_markup=new_task_markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def answer(call):
    match call.data:
        case 'name':
            bot.set_state(call.message.from_user.id, TaskStates.name, call.message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Введите название {bot.get_state(call.message.from_user.id,
                                                                                     call.message.chat.id)}')

        case 'description':
            bot.set_state(call.message.from_user.id, TaskStates.description, call.message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Введите описание {bot.get_state(call.message.from_user.id,
                                                                                     call.message.chat.id)}')

        case 'deadline':
            bot.set_state(call.message.from_user.id, TaskStates.deadline, call.message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, f'Введите сроки {bot.get_state(call.message.from_user.id,
                                                                                  call.message.chat.id)}')

        case 'save':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,f"Задача сохранена!")
            with bot.retrieve_data(call.message.from_user.id, call.message.chat.id) as data:
                print(data)

        case 'back':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, call.data)


@bot.message_handler(state=TaskStates.name)
def enter_task_name(message):
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['name'] = message.text
    print(message.text)


@bot.message_handler(state=TaskStates.description)
def enter_task_description(message):
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['description'] = message.text
        print(message.text)


@bot.message_handler(state=TaskStates.deadline)
def enter_task_deadline(message):
    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['deadline'] = message.text
        print(message.text)


# Обработчик кнопки 'Существующая задача'
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Существующая задача')
def handle_existing_task(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали "Существующая задача". Пожалуйста, выберите задачу из списка.')


# Обработчик кнопки 'Отчеты'
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Отчеты')
def handle_reports(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали "Отчеты". Здесь будут ваши отчеты.')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Help Information')


bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.StateFilter(bot))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


If any of name, description or deadline buttons was pressed, I set a corresponding state, but messasge handlers corresponding to that state are not working at all. bot.retrieve_data is always empty. How can I fix it?
